# How to debug when javascript doesn't load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, debugging

I have 2 sites using the same theme. (http://www.kentishtowner.co.uk and http://here-is.com/kentishtowner-old/ )

They are WP multisite subsites, both using the exact same child theme (same template files exactly).

However, the former website is not loading javascript, causing the masonry layout and mobile menu to not work!
I assume this is something to do with when I mapped the domains, or changed the URL from something like here-is.com/kentishtowner-new  to here-is.com/kentishtowner, before domain mapping...

As I am not a JS person, can someone give me some insight as to how I can go about debugging this?

I haven't slept a wink last night and it's now 11am - am getting an hour's shuteye, and would hugely appreciate any responses!

Thanks!

Comment: is there any errors in browser developer console?

Comment: No, it looks clear to me, but isn't that something you can see as well?
http://here-is.com/kentishtowner/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2015/02/Screen-Shot-2015-02-08-at-12.10.18.png

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have consoles where javascript errors are thrown.  They will tell you what error was thrown, and where it was thrown from.  Once you know that, you can google around to see if there is anything obvious to fix.

My guess, though, is that somewhere the site that isn't working is trying to use a script that was hosted on the working site. If that's the case, you just need to update the script paths.

--edit--

Fortunately for me (from what I hear), I have never used Wordpress.  Unfortunately for you, I don't know how to tell you where the `.js` files would be located, or how they are organized at all.

I usually debug in Chrome, so this is how you can check to see if your page is able / unable to get an external script.

1. When you are focused on the page you're having a problem on, hit `F12` to open up the dev tools in Chrome.
2. Click on the `Network` tab, and then hit `F5` to refresh the page.
3. Click on the `Type` table header, and look for files that say `text/javascript`.  Those will be the external script files your site is requesting.
4. Look at the `Status` column for each of those rows.  If it doesn't say `200 OK.`, then your page isn't able to access the corresponding script.

From there, you would need to find where those scripts are *supposed* to be located.  Once you know that, just find the scripts from the other site, and copy them into the correct location of the broken site.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, what is the best way of checking for this in order to highlight the difference in paths? The theme is the same.. (i.e. it's not a copy of the template files, it is EXACTLY the same template file used on both websites. And both websites are hosted in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome's console you'll see

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html:
>   "http://here-is.com/?dm=c078877dcf0e3101dc20cc337a8e4214&action=load&blogid=13&siteid=1&t=1522670393&back=http%3A%2F%2Fkentishtowner.co.uk%2F".

In fact, further digging shows that `here-is.com` is returning an empty response to that request.

[image: web inspector zero bytes]

The page is actually referring absolutely to a number of resources on `here-is.com` and that works fine when you access it via that domain, but has issues when you access via `www.kentishtowner.co.uk`. I don't know enough about your setup to say for sure how to resolve it but you probably need to configure the base URL of the project to tell it where it's being deployed, or if you can tell it to use relative links that would work too.

(In Chrome's developer tools you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type `here-is.com` to see the references)